# How to slow down the write speed of Kafka Producer?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I use the spark to write data to kafka in this way.

> df.write(). format("kafka"). save()

can I control the writing speed to kafka to avoid pressure on kafka?
Is there some options that helps to slow down the speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setting `linger.ms` to a non-zero value would help. As it controls the amount of time to wait for additional messages before sending the current batch. Code can look like the following

```java
df.write.format("kafka").option("linger.ms", "100").save()
```

But this really depends on a lot of things. If your Kafka is 'big' enough and configured properly, I wouldn't worry too much about the speed. After all, kafka is designed to cope with this situation (traffic spike).

Comment: Does this option work in spark strucutred streaming?

Comment: Sorry, I am answering this question from Kafka's perspective because I am more familiar with it. You'll have to try to find out if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Structured Streaming will try to process data as fast as possible by default. There are options in each source to allow to control the processing rate, such as maxFilesPerTrigger in File source, and maxOffsetsPerTrigger in Kafka source.

```
val streamingETLQuery = cloudtrailEvents
  .withColumn("date", $"timestamp".cast("date") // derive the date
  .writeStream
  .trigger(ProcessingTime("10 seconds")) // check for files every 10s
  .format("parquet") // write as Parquet partitioned by date
  .partitionBy("date")
  .option("path", "/cloudtrail")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/cloudtrail.checkpoint/")
  .start()

val df = spark.readStream
  .format("text")
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
  .load("text-logs")
```

Read the following links for more details:

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-KafkaSource.html
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-FileStreamSource.html
https://databricks.com/blog/2017/01/19/real-time-streaming-etl-structured-streaming-apache-spark-2-1.html
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: thanks for your answers! But I have to edit my question, it should be spark instead of structured streaming. And your answers seem to try to control the process rate while I try to slow the `kafka producer` in spark actually.